# Customizing Request Header description in Swagger UI using Springfox-Swagger2

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, springfox

I am using Springfox Swagger2 version 2.4.0, Springfox Swagger UI version 2.4.0 and Swagger Annotations version 1.5.0 in my Spring Boot application.

The question here is, I am able to generate swagger UI for my controller's API and I am able to test the same. But I am not able to specify request header description for my request header. I m using @RequestHeader annotation for the same.

The code snippet in my controller API is follows:

`@RequestHeader(name = "Api-Key")  String apiKey`

The Swagger UI for the request header is as follows:

[image]

The highlighted rectangular area in the image represents the description of the request header.

Currently it just picks up the data mentioned in the name attribute and shows it. But i wanna give a different description for the same. i.e. "Value of license key"

How can i achieve this in Swagger UI as @RequestHeader annotation only have value, defaultValue, name and required attributes? Any help would be really appreciated.

Update: Looking for a solution out of the box without any custom annotation of my own

Comment: Dont understand why this question is downvoted twice?

Comment: I am confused with RequestHeader exactly as described. ApiParam(name, value, ..) makes sense to me, and #value() is explicitely described for "description" (io.swagger.annotations v2.9.2 in my case). However the interface declaration of @RequestHeader in (spring-web.bind.annotations  5.0.12 in my case) declares #value() with an AliasFor("name") and #name() with an AliasFor("value") where setting of both at the same time results in a render error. Is this a bug or should this be reversed RequestHeader::value() should behave analog ApiParam::value() as a description field?

Comment: @Parameter(description = "description") seems to work as well

Answer (score 14):

Maybe my answer will help somebody.

As mentioned [Dilip Krishnan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19219/dilip-krishnan) in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42359301/616290) you could use `io.swagger.annotations.ApiParam` or `io.swagger.annotations.ApiImplicitParam` Swagger annotations for fine-tuned custom documentation.

`@ApiParam` could be used for registered method parameters.

`@ApiImplicitParam` could be used if API parameter wasn't registered explicitly.

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/v1/test", produces = "application/json")
@Api(value = "/v1/test")
public class TestController {
    
    @ApiOperation(value = "Do Something method", tags = "Test method")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/doSomeThing", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Foo doSomeThing(
            @ApiParam(value = "Param1 Description", required = true)
            @RequestParam String param) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("do Some Things");
    }
    
    @ApiOperation(value = "Do Something Another method", tags = "Test method")
    @ApiImplicitParams({
            @ApiImplicitParam(name = "anotherParam1", value = "Another Param1 Description", paramType = "header"),
            @ApiImplicitParam(name = "anotherParam1", value = "Another Param1 Description", paramType = "header")
    })
    @RequestMapping(value = "/doSomeThingAnother", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Foo doSomeThingAnother(Bar bar) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("do Some Thing Another");
    }
}
```

And in the end you could see following picture

[image: Swagger UI for custom method description]

Comment: I was looking for something to do on top of request header param. Unfortunately not api implicit param

Comment: Description was updated for regular request parameter.

Comment: `@ApiParam(value="header description")` can be used along with   `@RequestHeader` to provide header description. @DmytroBoichenko update the answer with this.

Comment: @ChackoMathew I'm sorry mate, but currently I don't have this code and can't check your solution.

Comment: @DmytroBoichenko I tried this way, but I can't see this value is sent as a header when I investigate the network tab of browser tools.

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR is that you would have to build your own plugin to do it.

Basically the only out-of-the-box annotations to augment the description in this case are `@ApiParam` and to be more accurate `@ApiImplicitParam`. Unfortunately neither of those annotations support descriptions.

So my suggestion would be to:

1. Create your own annotation that would look like this

   `@RequestHeader(name = "Api-Key")
    @Description("Value of license key") String apiKey`

NOTE: There is already an [annotation in spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Description.html) that is suitable for this.

2. Create your own [ParameterBuilderPlugin](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/blob/master/springfox-spring-web/src/main/java/springfox/documentation/spring/web/readers/parameter/ParameterRequiredReader.java#L45)
3. Implement the plugin as shown below

```java
public class Test implements ParameterBuilderPlugin {
  @Override
  public void apply(ParameterContext parameterContext) {
    ResolvedMethodParameter methodParameter =parameterContext.resolvedMethodParameter();
    Optional<Description> requestParam = methodParameter.findAnnotation(Description.class);
    if (requestParam.isPresent()) {
      parameterContext.parameterBuilder()
        .description(requestParam.get().value());
    }
  }

  @Override
  public boolean supports(DocumentationType documentationType) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

4. Pick a value of [the order](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/blob/master/springfox-spring-web/src/main/java/springfox/documentation/spring/web/readers/parameter/ParameterRequiredReader.java#L44) that is is applied [after swagger annotations](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/blob/master/springfox-swagger-common/src/main/java/springfox/documentation/swagger/common/SwaggerPluginSupport.java#L30) have been processed.

Also please upgrade your springfox library to the [latest version](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2).

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Dont have much exposure on things you say, so will try out and get back to you. Thanks again

Comment: Finally got time to start on this. But i m stuck at the start as i m fairly new to this. As you mentioned, i tried placing description annotation to my request header param and got an error like - "annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration" Can you guide me in this? Also should i place the test class in your post in my spring application code? Lastly, i m not very clear about what you meant in step-4 Please advice

Comment: When u create your annotation make sure it applies to parameters as well. Using the one that comes with spring may not work. Step 4 is simply saying make sure your plugin runs after swagger plugins. These plugins use springs Ordering for beans.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue, and resolved the problem in the following way:

```java
.. @RequestHeader(value = "..") @ApiParam(value = "Description") String param ..
```

The idea is to add "description" field into generated swagger. It could look hacky, but it's a quick simple solution which can be useful in your personal case.

Comment: Guess that will add a new param and not update the header description

Comment: Yep, right you are. If the goal is only swagger, it could help. But in general case it's better to use solutions above.

Answer (score 0):

Quick, easy valid solution is to use an `enum`, for example:

```
@RequestHeader(value = "someval") ALLOWED_VALUES input

private enum ALLOWED_VALUES {A, B, C};
```

The following will show in swagger:
Available values : `A, B, C`